# What is () defined as in Purescript? What does it mean?

Tags: purescript

What is `()` defined as? I see it in type signatures, I thought it was the unit type same as in Haskell but it seems instead Purescript uses `Unit`. So then what is `()`?

Using `spago repl` was not helpful either:

```
> :t ()                                                              
Unexpected token ')' at line 1, column 2
> :i ()
Unrecognized directive. Type :? for help.
> :k ()
Error found:
at :1:2 - 1:3 (line 1, column 2 - line 1, column 3)

  Type variable k is undefined.

while inferring the kind of k
while checking that type k
  has kind Type
while inferring the kind of () @k

See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/UndefinedTypeVariable.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Comment: I'm not very proficient with Purescript so I don't want to write an answer, but I believe it denotes an empty [row type](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Types.md#rows)

Comment: That is correct

Comment: So an empty row type has it's own type? Why is the repl reporting the `Unexpected token ')' at line 1, column 2` for `:t ()`?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski values have _types_, so by using `:type` you have to pass in a value. Types and rows instead have _kinds_, so you should be able to use the `:kind` command instead of `:type`.

Comment: That gives an error, as in the post (I'm using `:k ()` later on). Though perhaps that is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` is of kind `Row Type`. As one commentor mentioned, it is in fact the empty row type. I think that the parser struggles with it, if it is encountered randomly without context (e.g. after `:k`) because it could also be the start of a pair of parenthesis. It could probably be considered a bug. If you give it context, it works. It just completely defeats the point of using `:k` in the first place.

```
> :k () :: Row Type
Row Type
```

It can be used where row types are expected:

```
> :k Record
Row Type -> Type

> :k Record ()
Type
```

`Record ()` is the type of the empty record `{}`.

```
> :t {}
Record (() @Type)
```